# Problems with deploying to Heroku: missing 'secret_key_base' and uninitialized constant Posts (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

**Im using Rails 5.1.6; Ruby-Version 2.4.4; and the Figaro Gem**

After locally my RoR-App seemed to work i decided to deploy it to Heroku, but when i try to enter the website i get an Application Error. I looked up the logs and discovered an uninitailized constant (NameError)

```
/app/controllers/Posts/likes_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Posts (NameError)
```

Here is my likes_controller.rb:

```
class Posts::LikesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_post

  def show
    @post.likes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to @post}
      format.js
    end
  end

  def create
    @post.likes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to @post}
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    if @post.present?
      @like = Like.where(user_id: current_user.id, post_id: @post.id).first
      if @like.present?
        @like.destroy
        redirect_to post_path(@post), :notice => 'Unliked!'
      else
        redirect_to post_path(@post), :alert => 'An error prevented you from unliking 
this post!'
      end
    else
      redirect_to p, :alert => 'Invalid post!'
    end
  end

  private

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end
end
```

i tried running `heroku rake db:migrate` to match my database with my code but it is still giving me the same error. Then i thought maybe my migration are not correct but they seem to be correct after controlling in developement mode.
Then i tried to run rails locally in production mode with `rails s -e production` which gave me this Error:

```
2018-10-28 17:02:24 +0100: Rack app error handling request { GET / }
#<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value 
in `config/secrets.yml`>
```

which seemed for me to be pretty close to what my heroku logs were saying with:

```
2018-10-28T15:50:00.991935+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=c081e39f-f4f5-49e6-a7d3-3a72060762cb fwd="131.188.24.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

So i set my secret_key_base with `heroku run rake secret` and set the generated key as `heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE= 'generated key'` Afterwards i controlled that the key got set and all my other variables from figaro with `heroku config` and everything was correct. But i still got the same error/s.

At last i realized that in the NameError the **Posts** was written in upper-case which seemd unusual, so i corrected it to **posts** and deployed again, but i still get the same Error as before with `/controllers/Posts/likes_controller` so also written with upper-case.

now i am really out of ideas what my real problem is. So it would be nice if someone could help me out. Please let me know if you need more informations. Thanks

Comment: Your routes look like `posts/:id/likes` right? You may want to stuff this in a module instead of namespacing the class like that. `module Posts; class Likes ...` — also, downcase everything in your folder structure.

Comment: Since one Like is just a single action my routes look like `posts/:id/like` and in my routes.rb i got `resource :like , module: :posts ` in my resources posts do ... action if you meant this. I also downcased everything but although i deployed it again i get the same old folder structure in my Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Mistake was indeed the writing so i changed the folder **Posts** to **posts**. In order to deploy it to heroku i had to copy paste my app into a new directory so i could set a new git repo with `git init`. Otherwise it used my old and did not deployed the changing of a folder name.